# Grails create criteria simple problem

Tags: grails, criteria

How can i use "%" in criteria-like statements in this example:

```
def c = Shop.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    like("name", "Harrods")

def aha = params.name
    like("store.name", %aha%) ##
}
```

The "%aha%" part doesnt work. but it does work if i do "%ola%". So how to solve the problem ?

Or in addiction, instead of "%aha", how can i use criteria builder using 'contains' groovy method instead of like?

Comment: solution: like("store.name", "%" + aha + "%"

Comment: hida's solution is the 'groovier' way to do it, yours is a bit more Java-y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace the following

```
%aha%
```

with

```
 "%${aha}%"
```